# Angular ng-hide/ng-show directives not working

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I have an issue which presents on an Android 4.x device, but not on a newer device. I have no idea why, but I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a list using `ng-repeat`. Each item uses `ng-include` to load a template dynamically (this is a generic, reusable dialog).

```
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterItems(searchTerm) as filtered" ng-click="options.selectItem(item)" style="font-size: 14px; padding: 0;" tappable>
  <div class="left" style="width: 100%;">
    <ng-include src="'app/dialog/smartpick/'+options.itemTemplate" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px 16px;"></ng-include>
  </div>
</ons-list-item>
```

The template currently causing me issues contains a button like this:

```
<ons-button ng-click="openDocument(item, $event)" ng-if="item.SpecificationSpecDocumentID" style="float: right;font-size: 20px !important; padding: 0px 10px;">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-image" ng-hide="item.opening" style="vertical-align: middle;"></ons-icon>
    <ons-icon icon="ion-load-b" ng-show="item.opening" class="spin" style="vertical-align: middle;"></ons-icon>
</ons-button>
Debug: {{ item.opening }}
```

When `openDocument` is called, it does this (among other things):

```
if(item.opening) return; 
item.opening = true;
```

When the list is rendered, both of the `<ons-icon>` elements are shown; the `ng-show`/`ng-hide` directives do not seem to do anything. The debug text under the button shows true or false respectively, but no class or style is added to the icon elements. (I also tried isolating the problem by moving the directives to wrapper `<span>` elements, but it didn't have any effect.)

As I said before, this work fine on a newer device. Any clues as to what may cause directives to fail or be ignored on older devices?

**EDIT**

It certainly has something to do with the child scope created inside the `<ons-button>` element, because the directives work outside of that scope. I just don't know why it would work in newer webviews but not the older one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the browser version had to do with it, but it seems the problem was a consequence of using `ng-if` in my templates. When I changed those into `ng-show`, the problem disappeared.